# Regex to match up to the last occurrence of "$" and replace everything to the right

Tags: python, regex

Context: I want to use Python to iterate over a bunch of json documents (cosmodb) and remove the last portion of a string in the value of a key

I want to turn this:

```
"id": "randomstuff-channelruleprintermap-1234-$pc2$randomstuff$1234$uspc02"
```

into this:

```
"id": "randomstuff-channelruleprintermap-1234-$pc2$randomstuff$"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: It is a $ followed by zero or more characters which are everything except a $.

Comment: In your example you also remove the number between second-to-last and last $.

Comment: while that's helpful,  I really wouldn't be asking if I hadn't stressed google first :(

Comment: Then you should edit the question to show what you tried as properly formatted text. A helpful resource to play around with regex is also https://regex101.com/

Comment: .+?(?<=\$randomstuff\$) ... yay me thanks for inspiring the collaborative spirit Michael

Comment: Well, I understand where you're coming from Michael but not responding would have provided the same value as your response sans the cynicism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily implement this with this piece of code:

```py
result = my_string.rsplit('$', 1)[0] + "$"
```

Which behaves like this:

```py
>>> my_string = "randomstuff-channelruleprintermap-1234-$pc2$randomstuff$1234$uspc02"
>>> print(my_string.rsplit('_', 1)[0])
"randomstuff-channelruleprintermap-1234-$pc2$randomstuff$"
```